# Sample space of random sum; Wald's equation

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading proof of Wald's equation in Durrett's *Probability theory and examples 5th ed*, but for me, it's indeed strange the statement itself.
Wald's equation is following:

> Let $X_1 , X_2, ...$ be i.i.d. with $E\lvert X_i \rvert < \infty$.
> Let N be stopping time with $EN<\infty$, then $ES_N = EX_1EN$

But I have following question: "What is $S_N$?"
Reason that I have confusing is if I write all argument, then it would be $S_{N(\omega)} (\tau)$
Then what will be sample space and probability function?
I think $S_N$ is function from $\Omega \times\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Hence it will equip probability function $P\times P$, in the sense of product measure.

With this point, meaning of expectation in $S_N$ should be differ to that of $S_n$.
Because $E[S_N] = \int_{\Omega \times \Omega} S_N d(P\times P)$, but $E[S_n] = \int_{\Omega} S_n dP$.
So I think compare expectation of $S_N$ and $S_n$ looks strange for me in Wald's equation.
But proof starts with equation $ES_N = \int S_N dP = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int S_n 1_{\{N=n\}} dP$.

How can I solve this problem?

edit:
I understand second equality in the sense of $S_{N(\omega)}(\tau) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n(\tau) 1_{\{\omega: N(\omega) = n\}}(\omega)$, but how first comes? I think first equality should be $ES_N = \int S_N d(P\times P)$

Comment: One can still understand $S_N$ as a measurable function $\omega\mapsto S_{N(\omega)}(\omega)$ from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That was just simple. Thanks